# Transform a database query to a useful format

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, pgadmin

I have a table on my database, I fetched the first row of my table and the result looks like this:

```
(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 3, 16, 27, 29, 198000), 'buy', Decimal('0.00276851'), Decimal('6.00000000'), 1, None)
```

However, on my database `(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 3, 16, 27, 29, 198000)` is a timestamp but here it is a string. How can I transform this result into a timestamp format that I could use later on my code? Thanks!

This is my code so far:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=monty user=postgres host=localhost password=*****")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM binance.zrxeth_aggregated FETCH first 1 rows only;")
row = cur.fetchone()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python-to-Postgres types table psycopg2's](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) documentation, this is the intended behavior. Postgres's `timestamp` becomes `datetime` object in Python.

Then, if you really need the timestamp value, it is just a matter of calling `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` on your `datetime` object:

- [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python)